# Monospace font for junit in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

How can I change the font in the JUnit tab so that it displays the results using a monospaced font?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Groovy, I have found the solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/GettingStarted).  You need to go to Groovy>Preferences and check the use monospace font checkbox.

[image]

Comment: This option is now deprecated in GGTS.  Has anyone figured out a substitute setting?

Comment: @10GritSandpaper it seems that there is a fix for the Eclipse 4.4 version [https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411794][link]. However it seems there is no way around this issue for the GGTS users, until there is a new GGTS based on Eclipse 4.4.

Comment: @AlexFedulov the link you provided doesn't give me proper solutions.