# Monospace font for junit in eclipse deprecated

Tags: eclipse, groovy, junit, spock, spring-tool-suite

I am using Spock and want monospaced output in the jUnit tab in Eclipse, but the option that is described in this Q/A ([Monospace font for junit in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348238/monospace-font-for-junit-in-eclipse)) is deprecated. Does anyone know a workaround ?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I'm using the most recent version of GGTS, which is (if I recall correctly) based on Eclipse 4.3. I'm on mobile at the moment, but I can give exact version numbers when I get back to my computer.

Comment: The Groovy Eclipse folks were so kind to reenable the feature. It already ships with the latest nightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jspresso Spock plugin solves this problem beautifully. :)  I just installed version 2.8.0.

After you install it, you need to right click on you project and select Jspresso > Add Spock Nature.  That's it.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because the Groovy Eclipse folks were so kind to contribute this feature to Eclipse 4.4 M1 (thanks!), which is where it really belongs. (See [Add a monospace font option for the junit results view](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411794).) However, I very much hope they will keep supporting the feature for older Eclipse versions, as it will take years until a majority of Spock users have moved to Eclipse 4.4. And it doesn't just affect Spock code, but also all Groovy code leveraging `assert` statements. I'll try to get in contact with the authors.

Comment: If Netbeans doesn't allow to configure the font, you should submit a feature request.

Comment: I submitted NetBeans feature request 233521  https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233521 . Feel free to revise if I didn't describe spock's use of JUnit test runner correctly.

Comment: Is there a solution for those who use GGTS and are stuck with the Eclipse 4.3 version?

Comment: Yes: Move to latest version of Groovy Eclipse plugin (not sure if it's already released, but the nightly did the job for me). From what I read, the Eclipse Spock plugin (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spock-plugin#.UjfNWmRgbDg) provides the same feature, so this might be another solution.

Comment: The Jspresso plugin did not change anything for me. The option is still disabled. Do you remember, where did you grab the nightly for Groovy Eclipse ?

Comment: UPD: The snapshot Groovy Eclipse 2.9 version from here http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/ helped. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the snapshot release of the Groovy Eclipse plugin (version 2.9.x) from here: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/

Comment: when I click that link I get an empty file.

Comment: This is not a link to directly download anything, but a so called "eclipse update site". Depending on the version of eclipse you are using you have to go to Help-> Install new software or  Help > Software Updates > Find and Install... (for eclipse indigo and older) and add this link there. When selected it will allow you to see the software components available from this resource. Please refer to the standard documentation for your eclipse version if this description is not detailed enough.