# How to make eclipse junit stacktrace use non-proportional font?

Tags: groovy, spock, eclipse-kepler

I'm using the Groovy Spock testing framework.  One nice thing that it does is print error messages that spell out exactly what parts of an expression didn't match an expectation, like the following:

```
project.yangGenerate.sourceDir == "/abcx"
|       |            |         |
|       |            null      false
|       task ':yangGenerate'
root project 'test'
```

This is nice.  However, when I run this test in Eclipse Kepler, the "Failure Trace" view looks like this:
[image: Snapshot of Failure Trace view]

I'm guessing the lines don't line up because Eclipse is using a proportional font to display this.  The "General"->"Appearance"->"Colors and Fonts" section of the Eclipse preferences would seemingly control this, but I find it very hard to figure out what section in that tree of preferences would control the font for this.  Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348238/monospace-font-for-junit-in-eclipse

Comment: Well, the good news is, this works.  The bad/questionable news is that right next to that field, it says "(deprecated)", so I don't know what I should expect this to do in the near future.

Comment: Supposedly this is resolved in Luna, where there is now a specific font property for this, so you can set it to a non-proportional font.

Answer (score 3):

You can set JUnit failure trace font to Consolas
[image: Colors and Fonts]